# Add Fileinput to Treemap

Tags: java, file-io, treemap

I can't add the file input to my map. It says I am missing something and that the Items []is not instantiated. I can't seem to figure it out

```
public class BigCities {

    private Map<String, Set<CityItem>> countryMap;
    private File file;


public BigCities(String fileName) {
    countryMap = new TreeMap<>();
    file = new File(fileName);
    readFile(fileName);
}

private void readFile(String fileName) {
    // Opg 3c implementeres her.

    CityItem cityItem;

    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();
        String[] items;

        while (line != null) {

            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            line.split(";");
            line = br.readLine();
            cityItem = new CityItem(items[1], items[2], items[3]);
        }
        String everything = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(everything);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }


public String toString() {
    return countryMap.toString();
}


/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Vaelg ANSI eller UTF8 afhaengig af hvad der virker bedst paa din computer:
    BigCities bc = new BigCities("EuroCities ANSI.txt");
    //BigCities bc = new BigCities("EuroCities UTF8.txt");
    System.out.println(bc);
}

}
```

I Don't know what I am missing to add the input, but hopefully someone has some input. 
I Am new to programming and therefore I find it confusing, since I feel like I am following all the right methods.

Comment: Please, don't paraphrase error messages. Post the exact and complete error you get.

Comment: Error:(41, 41) java: variable items might not have been initialized

Comment: So that means that at line 41, you're trying to use a local variable named `items` that you never initialized before. What is line 41? I guess it's `cityItem = new CityItem(items[1], items[2], items[3]);`. And indeed, you never initialized `items` before. You call `line.split(";");`, but ignore what it returns instead of initializing items with it.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize the `items` array, so when trying to access it, you're getting null, or it may just be caught by the compiler and will give you an error there.

I suspect that you mean to assign the split to items, so change the line

```
line.split(";");
```

to

```
items = line.split(";");
```